# Excel formatting breaks with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

**Problem:**

I am using `openpyxl.load_workbook()` to open/edit and save my excel file, but I find that the format breaks when opening the excel file on a machine with specific excel version.

Keep in mind that before opening/editing/saving the excel file using the `openpyxl` library, the format is how it is supposed to be on all machines/excel versions.

This is the specific snippet of my code that breaks the format:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename=file, data_only=False)
wb.save(file)
```

Regarding the two excel versions I am using:

When using the machine with **excel version 2212** to run the above lines, the format of my excel file is correct when opening the file on machines with the same excel format.
On the other hand, when trying to open the file on a machine with **excel version 2101**, everything inside the excel file format wise is broken, all formatting is gone.

On the other hand, when using the machine with **excel version 2101** to run the above lines, the format of my excel file is broken. It doesn't matter from which machine I open the excel file, it will always be broken, and all formatting is gone regardless.

This is an example of the exact same file open in two different machines:
[image]
[image: ![enter image description here]

Is there a way to save an excel file using the openpyxl file without breaking the format of my excel file, regardless of what the excel version is? I tried to find the solution but none of the other questions in here really seemed to helped

Comment: Looks like Excel fixed some longstanding bug. Openpyxl follows the specification, not any version.

Answer (score 0):

When I don't use the wb.save() line, I am able to retain the conditional formatting in the newly written file. I know it is not the best way.